# AngularJS: Filtering through a table with multiple keywords

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a problem with filtering with a search bar. Currently the filter that is in place functions but it has unwanted functionality. Because it is filtering through a JSON it will display table fields that are not based on the actual shown information because it's linked to it in parts of the JSON that are unused.

As such I want a filter which only queries against what is shown in the table. I have been trying to utilise searchKeyword like so:

`<input ng-model="searchKeyword.c.reference"/>`

This works but this is only one of the table columns. What I want to do is have multiple. However the following is not valid.

`<input ng-model="searchKeyword.c.reference && c.otherStuff"/>`

Is there a way to have multiple in the statement (from what I can find the answer seems to be no) or will I need a custom filter and if so what would be the best approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using || "OR" instead of && "AND" on ng-model?

Comment: Already tried that. It does not work sadly.